# Set up the right rule get now 500 error

Tags: mysql, joomla1.6

```
$db->setQuery("UPDATE #__customers (customers_default_address_id) 
               SET (customers_default_address_id = address_book_id 
               FROM #__address_book WHERE customers_id = '.(int) $userId.')");
```

With this rule I get a 500 error. What should be the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve the problem

```
$address_id = tep_db_insert_id();

$db->setQuery(" UPDATE #_customers 
                SET customers_default_address_id = '" . (int)$address_id . "'
                where customers_id = '" . (int) $userId . "'");
$db->query();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `UPDATE` syntax:

```
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
$db->setQuery("UPDATE customers c
           INNER JOIN address_book ab ON (...join-criterion_here...)
           SET c.customers_default_address_id = ab.address_book_id 
           WHERE c.customers_id = '$user_id' ");
```

Also the `'.(int) $user_id.'` trick doesn't work in my tests.

Comment: The information comes from address_book_id, this number replace the old number of customers_default_address_id. unfortunately nothing happends.